# Jetpack Compose Navigation, when I navigate to another screen the code of that screen seems to run multiple times

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "main") {
    composable("main"){
              mainscreen(navController)
        }
    composable("sub"){
              subscreen(navController)
        }
}

@Composable
fun mainscreen(navController:NavController){

    println("main")

    Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("sub") }) {
        Text(text = "go to sub")
    }
}

@Composable
fun subscreen(navController:NavController){

    println("sub")

    Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("main")}) {
        Text(text = "go to main")
    }
}
```

This is my code, it's the simplest demo I can find about Jetpack Compose Navigation. The problem is, when I checked the Terminal output, **I found the "println()" ran multiple times**, which indicates that any code in this screen will run multiple times as well. I think this will cause a lot issues when I write more code in. Is there any way to prevent this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSHF8.png)

As I delete the button in subscreen, the output shows only three println().

```
//only jump to subscreen and do nothing.
I/System.out: main
I/System.out: sub
I/System.out: main
```

what I think is the 1st one is due to the change of navController(since there's a change, so the composable re-compose itself?). Then 2nd one is due to the calling up of the subscreen(as it should be only once). The 3rd one I don't know where it comes from(why mainscreen re-compose itself again?).

If I keep two buttons in my two screens(so I can jump from one to another), the the output shows five println() after I click the button and jump to the subscreen from mainscreen.

```
//only jump to subcreen and do nothing.
I/System.out: main
I/System.out: sub
I/System.out: main
I/System.out: sub
I/System.out: sub
```

There're two extra println("sub") which means subscreen does again re-compose itself twice.
I don't know why.

shouldn't it be like this?

```
//jump to subcreen
I/System.out: sub

//jump to maincreen
I/System.out: main
```